# Burning Intel Microcontroller using AVR programmer

Tags: microcontroller

Is it possible to load hex file created to Intel 8051 micro controller using AVR USBISP programmer

This is the Datasheet..
http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/Intel/mXqzvzz.pdf

Comment: dunno about intel, but ATMEL 8051s can be programmed that way.

Comment: The original Intel 8051s were mask-programmed ... are you sure you're looking at a programmable part? It fact, add a link to its datasheet in the question.

Comment: @Jasen  Would you be so kind as to avoid using street colloquialisms such as "dunno" and "yeah" on EE.SE?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Here is the Datasheet http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/Intel/mXqzvzz.pdf

Comment: Many other companies have released improved second-source versions of the old intel 8051, including Philips, Atmel, Dallas/Maxim, and many others... and there are many variants within the 8051 family, including 8031 or 8032. So the answer depends on the exact manufacturer and part number, not just "generic intel 8051" as your question currently implies. If you're not sure you recognize the manufacturer's logo, post a photo and request identification. And better datasheets are usually found on the original manufacturer's own website.

Comment: @Goutam Are you absolutely sure that it is the datasheet for your actual processor? Because later on you mention "P80C51", which is a different chip, made by Philips (now NXP).

Comment: This datasheet explains in detail how the various standard 8051 features work: [nxp.com 8051 datasheet](http://nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/8XC51_8XC52.pdf)  Figure 14. External Program Memory Read Cycle shows the timing signals for reading firmware from an external memory (External Access EA# pin configured to logic low).

Comment: @Goutam: the datasheet you inidcate describes a UVPROM version of the 8051 - the internal program memory is erased by exposure to UV light (the package will have a quartz window to allow the chipp to be exposed to the light).  The part is then placed in an EPROM programmer to write our program into the part.  That 8051 version cannot be programmed using the AVR USBISP or similar in-circuit programmers.  I'm sure that there are other versions (by Atmel and others) that can use In-circuit programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet confirms my suspicions : you don't program these, using AVR or any other programmer.

Instead, you send your finished and fully debugged program to Intel, and they mask it directly onto the device, before packaging it and sending it to you. (Minimum order, 10000 probably). Or more likely tell you that the last buy date was about 10 years ago...

As your 80C51s are already packaged, there is nothing you can do with them except whatever they are originally programmed to do. Ask whoever you bought them from for full information...

Either the 87C51 with its EPROM can be programmed, or the Atmel variety, (or TI or another 3rd party version with Flash or EEPROM can be programmed, but not the original. The date code will give you some idea how old they are - probably about 20 years old (probably 4 digits, beginning 95 or so).

[Related Q&A...](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69805/how-did-handheld-video-games-from-the-70s-and-80s-work/69813#69813)

EDIT : Dim memory , backed up by the comment from MarkU...
It is also possible to bypass the internal ROM, and add an external EPROM (or more modern equivalent). The 8031 was a variant without the internal ROM, but I believe you can use the 8051 this way too.

The disadvantage in that you need (1) an external ROM, (2) an external address latch (like a 74HC373) and (3) you lose 16 of your GPIO pins, specifically P0 and P2. For details how to operate the chip in this mode, see the datasheet. (I think it's as simple as wiring the EA/VPP pin to 0V).

Comment: What can I do with it then?

Comment: @Brian Drummond: The datasheet I read describes a UVPROM part, although I suspect there were mask programmed versions as well.

Comment: @PeterBennett : I'm guessing that's for the Philips/NXP version rather than Intel? Or if it's Intel, it covers both 8751 (EPROM) and 8051 (mask) in the same datasheet, right?

Comment: @Brian Drummond: It was an Intel datasheet that claimed to cover 8051, 8751, and 8031.  It does state that the 8031 has no program memory, but I can't find any mention of the 8051 being mask programmed (or what the diffference between 8051 and 8751 is).  I think I used 8751s (UVPROM) and later, Atmel equivalents that were in-circuit programmable.

Comment: Right. If it's like the linked one in the question, note (1) a section called "Programming the 8751" and no instructions for programming the others, and (from Page 1) "When ordering the 80C51BHP, customers must submit the 64 byte encryption table together with the ROM code"

Answer (score 1):

No. Intel never made 8051 parts that were in circuit programmable. They had some 87xxx parts that were EPROM based but those were generally programmed in a dedicated programming fixture that provided the necessary high voltage programming pulses. So applications with those parts required sockets for the MCU.

Comment: I have a part called P80C51.. If it is not programmable then what can I do with that?

Comment: @Goutam: you can't do anything with it, unless the existing program does something useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The programmer you reference, the AVR, appears to be specific to Atmel AVR micro-controllers. The answer to your question is most likely no. There are many flavors of 8051 controllers (Atmel makes then  also) that are available with EA prom and ARE programmable, but you will need to research this and get the programmer that is correct for the application.

In the past I have worked with several products that used 8051 controllers, and we had a C compiler and programmer that we used to write code and burn into the the prom on the chip, so this is definitely possible, you just need the correct equipment.